# Neo4j Web Console - Overtype mode change

Tags: neo4j, editor

Is there any way in Neo4j web console editor to change overtype mode of input to insert type?

I am using neo4j version 3.3.3 installed on ubuntu 16 server.

The next question is why I can't find solution for this simple issue by google: O

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the "Overtype Mode" by simply pressing `Insert` on your keyboard. This is a common procedure to toggle this mode in most editors. This worked for me in the Neo4j Browser. I hope this helps you aswell.
 [image]

Comment: Inserty key doesnt works so I started searching is there  any  special way to change this mode. Maybe this is common issue where  standard fixing method will repair it (running PC once again)

Comment: Thats weird. I tested it before I wrote the answer. For me it worked in the normal browser and in the desktop version aswell. I remember having this issue a year ago.

Comment: Unfortunetly on other PC I have the same issue. I ve tried also complex shortcuts with insert key adding ctrl or shift.I used also chrome and Firefox browsers. If solution is simple likie you wrote I have very specific issue.

Comment: Yes seems so. I will let this answer as it is because it might help others. Also others can read the comments to see that this isn't working for you. Can you provide further information like the version you use and stuff like this and add it to your question? Because the insert key wasn't working for me a couple of months ago But i never expierenced this problem again.